# Showing $\frac{|BC|^2}{|AB|\cdot|DB|}+\frac{|CA|^2}{|AB|\cdot|AD|}-\frac{|CD|^2}{|AD|\cdot|DB|}=1$, for $D$ on side $AB$ of $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have some problems with the following proof:

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show for every $D\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $D\in\overline{AB}$:
>
> $$\frac{|BC|^2}{|AB|\cdot|DB|}+\frac{|CA|^2}{|AB|\cdot|AD|}-\frac{|CD|^2}{|AD|\cdot|DB|}=1$$

It looks like I have to use the angles in the triangle, but I have no idea to start the proof. Does anyone have an idea to start ?

Comment: it's called Stuart's theorem and the proof is just two applications of theorem of cosines. Easily available on wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint :-)

Comment: I tried to prove it but there is a problem; so I found Stewart's theorem on wikipedia and it is not the same : $\bar{AB}\neq|AB|; \bar{DB}\neq|DB|...$

Comment: Here's how I did it: in $\Bbb C, A=0, B=1, C=\xi +i\eta, D=x$, starting by looking at the case $x>1$.

Comment: It IS NOT "$-$"; it is $+$.Is not it ?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As pointed out by  dezdichado, the problem can be done by two applications of Cosine Formula.

Refer to the figure,

One such formula is:

$$\cos \alpha=\frac{(c-x)^2+y^2-a^2}{2(c-x)y}$$

Applying Cosine Formula to the other triangle and combining the $2$ equations would yield the required answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea to start :

In $\Bbb C, A=0, B=1, C=\xi +i\eta, D=x$

Unfortunately, none of my calculations succeed, although simplifications appear: I suspect that there is a sign error in the proposed equality.